# "x-robots-tag: none" on Gatsby site hosted by Gatsby Cloud with Contentful

Tags: gatsby, contentful

I created Gatsby.js website hosted by Gatsby Cloud(Individual Trial Plan) and using Contentful. Although I didn't set Robot.txt, the production site automatically had `x-robots-tag: none` at HTTP header. This caused Google Search Console to show error 'noindex tag is added'.

Could you kindly help me how to remove `x-robots-tag: none` and set `x-robots-tag: all`.

I have already tried to use proper robot.txt with `gatsby-plugin-robots-txt` but never solved.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [GatsbyJs support](https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056430174-How-can-I-make-my-site-private-)

> By default, all Previews, Builds, and PR Builds are set to Public. We set an x-robots-tag: none Header to prevent search engines from crawling your site that is hosted on the gtsb.io domain.

Add your domain and run LH again

Comment: I can confirm that it only shows that in the internal Lighthouse report, the external shows me:

 Page isn’t blocked from indexing

Answer (score 2):

Hi have you tried with  `no-index` attribute of [gatsby-plugin-next-seo](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-next-seo/?=seo#no-index)

> This property works in tandem with the nofollow property and together they populate the robots and googlebot meta tags.